# UI Not Updating with Child View Controllers

Tags: swift4.2

I am using child view controllers to help implement a radio player.  Besides a couple of popups (info, share etc) it is only one main view.

Unless it is called/implemented by the "master view controller" my children UI components will not update.  I can see the the variable, via "print" statement being passed using a struct, delegation, injections, didSet etc.  So I know the "data" is not the issue.  The next logical step would be to ensure it was call on the main que.  That also didn't help.

So my question becomes, is it a bad thing to update from the master view controller?  (Besides the couple hundred lines of code!)  Suggestions on things I may not have tried or missed?

Comment: By the way I am doing this all programmatically.